# 10x10 grid of 100 buttons: hiding a button on click (C#)

Tags: c#, events

I have a 10x10 grid of 100 buttons, I want to hide a button when it is clicked.

Is there a way to apply this to all buttons?? i.e. When any of the button is clicked then that button is hidden. I use a table layout to arrange the 100 buttons in C#.

also im adding it to table layout so kindly tell me how to add these buttons to that 10x10 table grid..here how will the button objects be named and how to add individual events all performing the action to itself(that is hide itself when clicked)

Comment: Winforms, Web, WPF, or Silverlight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create 100 buttons

```
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
{
    foreach (int j in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
        b.Location = new Point(i * 20, j * 20);
        b.Click += new EventHandler(anyButton_Click); // <-- all wired to the same handler
        this.Controls.Add(b);
    }
}
```

and connect them all to the same event handler

```
void anyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (sender as Button);
    if (button != null)
    {
        button.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

in the eventhandler you cast `sender` to `Button` and that is the specific button that was pressed.

Comment: The eventhandler approach here works for both WinForms and WebForms. The loop creating the buttons would be slightly different for webforms...

Comment: Why do you use `foreach` in that way? It doesn't seem so cleaner than using a normal `for` loop. I clarify that I don't want to criticize how you code, I'm just curious :)

Comment: @AS-CII - foreach is in fact cleaner way to implement looping. It saves you from off by one errors and it does not impact performance by any means.

Comment: @AS-CII, just to avoid my brain having a monotonous meltdown.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using tablelayoutpanel, you don't need to calculate positions for the buttons, the control is doing it for you. You can also set the buttons dock property to be fill, so you don't need to setup size of the buttons. All  you'll have to do is to setup the properties of the tableLayoutPanle

So..

```
Button b;
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100))
{

        b = new Button();
        //b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20); 
        b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        b.Click += new EventHandler(anyButton_Click); // <-- all wired to the same handler
        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(b);

}
```